# Squid 3.4 transparent https proxy

Tags: proxy, https, squid

I'm trying to get a transparent https proxy setup working. I'm not looking to intercept or anything, I would like the https traffic to just be forwarded to the real host.

In squid I have something like:
https_port 3130 cert=/etc/ssl/certs/host1.crt key=/etc/ssl/private/host1.key

However when I make a web request I'm prompted with the ssl certificate is invalid warning screen.

Am I doing something wrong? I tried adding 'transparent' to https_port and squid 3.4 won't start.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to generate a certificate request and then get it signed by a certification authority. You will have to use openssl for that.

You also have to redirect https incoming traffic from port 443 to port 3130. I think iptables is most suitable for that.

I would suggest to read this : http://ajayadas.com/e110body-anchor/

Hope this helps a little.

Comment: I've done both. Let's say I have a cert like myhost.crt. If I visit https://anotherhost.com I get an error that the certificate is for myhost.crt and not anotherhost.com.

Comment: Normal behaviour ! you can add alternates names to your certificate request : add anotherhost.com as an alternate name to your request

Comment: If that's the case the user would have to accept a root CA.

Comment: yep, the user will have to accept the root CA. To avoid this you can use real CA like Verisign or Digicert but it has a cost !